# how do i get the code to print the integers i have entered instead of these numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I enter my 7 integers "1 2 3 4 2 6 2" it will print the correct number of occurrences. However it will print the numbers at "49 50 51 52 53 54 55"... What in my code is missing or what do I need to change in order to get it print the correct numbers?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final int maxEntryCount = 7;
    int [][] numbers = new int [maxEntryCount][2];
    System.out.print("Enter " + maxEntryCount + " integers separated by spaces: ");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxEntryCount; i++) {
        numbers[i][0] = (input.next().charAt(0));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxEntryCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < maxEntryCount; j++) {
            if (numbers[i][0] > 0 && numbers [j][0] == numbers[i][0]) {
                numbers[i][1]++;
                if (j > i) {
                    numbers[j][0] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maxEntryCount; i++) {
        if (numbers[i][0] > 0) {
            System.out.println("Number " + numbers[i][0] + " occurs " + (int) numbers[i][1] + " times");
            if (numbers[i][0] == 1) {
                System.out.println("Number " + numbers[i][0] + " occurs " + (int) numbers[i][1] + " time");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just change your loop where you are getting the `user input` to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxEntryCount; i++) {
    numbers[i][0] = (input.nextInt());
}
```

In your code you were reading the input as character. When you type `1` then it will take its `ASCII` value instead of `1`.
I changed it to `input.nextInt()` which is used to take int as input.